# Any free memory leak detector for Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leak-detector

I'm looking for free memory leak detector for `Qt`. I use `Qt Creator 1.3` with `Qt version 4.6 (32 bit)`. The platform is `Windows 7 Ultimate`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows) is not Qt-specific, the answers do refer to various general-purpose memory leak detection tools which are available on Windows.  The two which are mentioned in the accepted answer are commercial tools, but there are some free alternatives referred to in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Qt in particular, but I use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for memory-leak tracking.

**EDIT**: Valgrind doesn't work on Windows, so this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: -1 since the OP stated that the platform is Windows, for which Valgrind is not available. Have posted a link to another question which refers to memory leak detection tools on Windows specifically.

Comment: It's not? :) Sorry - I assumed it was.

Answer (score -1):

I have used Valgrind on a major graphical Qt product. Like any software tool it takes serious effort to learn how to use it and configure it efficiently. I am still a newbie at using it really but I find it very useful and beneficial to find memory issues. It can slow the debugged program to a very noticeable extent. I still recommend it though.

The lack of a memory debugging mechanism in Qt is a somewhat surprising omission for a commercial C++ framework.

Comment: -1 since the OP stated that the platform is Windows, for which Valgrind is not available. Have posted a link to another question which refers to memory leak detection tools on Windows specifically.